# Calculate invoice form with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create dynamic invoice form which calculates sums once numbers are entered. I have combination of input fields and drop down (select). I do not know how to combine these two types. I know for select I should use "onchange" but not sure how to combine with the rest.

And the next step, to have dynamic form, is to be able add (and remove) rows. I have no idea how I would add it. I realize I need unique names for each item.

```js
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    var qty1  = Number($('#qty1').val());
    var price1 = Number($('#price1').val());
  var percentage1  = Number($('#percentage1').val());

    $('#sum1').html(qty1 * price1);
    $('#total1').html(qty1 * price1 * percentage1);    
/*
    var qty2  = Number($('#qty2').val());
    var price2 = Number($('#price2').val());
  var percentage2  = Number($('#percentage2').val());

    $('#sum2').html(qty2 * price2);
    $('#total2').html(qty2 * price2 * percentage2); 

   $('#grand_total').html(total1 + total2);    
*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
  <tr><td>name</td><td>quantity</td><td>price</td><td>sum</td><td>%</td><td>total</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item1" size=15 required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qty1" size=5 required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="price1" size=5 required /></td>
    <td><span id="sum1"></span></td>
    <td><select name="percentage1"><option value="0.1">10%</option><option value="0.2">20%</option></select></td>
    <td><span id="total1"></span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  
  <p>
  grand total: <span id="grand_total"></span>
  </p>
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way it will work:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
    calculate();
});

$('select').change(function(){
    calculate();
});

function calculate(){
    var qty1  = Number($('#qty1').val());
    var price1 = Number($('#price1').val());
    var percentage1  = Number($('#percentage1').val());
    $('#sum1').html(qty1 * price1);
    $('#total1').html(qty1 * price1 * percentage1);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
  <tr><td>name</td><td>quantity</td><td>price</td><td>sum</td><td>%</td><td>total</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="item1" size=15 required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="qty1" size=5 required /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="price1" size=5 required /></td>
    <td><span id="sum1"></span></td>
    <td><select id="percentage1"><option value="0.1">10%</option><option value="0.2">20%</option></select></td>
    <td><span id="total1"></span></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
  
  <p>
  grand total: <span id="grand_total"></span>
  </p>
```

Comment: Thank you Marco, I did not realize I need to call the same function on both, keyup and change. And last question, how can I calculate grand total when I have two (or more rows)? (Sorry I am noob in this)
https://jsfiddle.net/sgpb68vt/3/